# Почему Convert.ChangeType не может конвертировать из char в double (или float)

Tags: c#, типы

У меня есть такой метод:

```
    public static T To<T>(this char o)
        where T : struct
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(T));
    }
```

Если я на месте T стоит double (или float), то выдается `InvalidCastException` с текстом вроде `System.InvalidCastException: Недопустимое приведение "Char" к "Double".`
Ну что не так с double? Тип явно больше char. Сейчас этот метод выглядит так:

```
public static T To<T>(this char o)
        where T : struct
    {
        var obj = Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(int));
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
    }
```

Сам вопрос - в заголовке. Это как-то объясняется где-нибудь с точки зрения логики? Я ответа не нашел.

Comment: [так в реализации IConvertible типа Char метода ToDouble](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,489)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Why is Convert.ToDouble(char) not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313092/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо. Оформите это как ответ?

Comment: Оформил, но как ни странно ясности _почему это так работает_ не особо добавило :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) внутри себя пытается [привести аргумент к `IConvertible`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,338) и вызвать соответствующий метод.

Для случая с `Char`, будет вызываться его [метод `.ToDouble`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,489)

```
/// <internalonly/>
double IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider) {
    throw new InvalidCastException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidCast_FromTo", "Char", "Double"));
}
```

В котором явно бросается исключение.

---

#### Почему метод `.ToDouble` не поддерживается?

Не только этот метод. `.ToBoolean`, `.ToDateTime`, `.ToDecimal` и `.ToSingle` тоже не поддерживаются, все они бросают `InvalidCastException` так же как и `.ToDouble`.

В этом случае дизайн .NET пытается уберечь вас от проблем. Преобразование `char` в целые типы имеет смысл, вы можете посмотреть на таблицы Unicode и посчитать количество `codepoint`. Но что должно означать преобразование в `Boolean`? Какой из `Unicode code point` будет `True`? Как символ вообще может быть *дробным* значением? Нет половинных или четвертных `codepoint`.

<sub>перевод ответа [@HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313092/2881286)</sub>

---

Стоит так же отметить, что [тип `char` может быть неявно преобразован в тип `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `float`, `double` или `decimal`.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char#conversions)

То есть следующий код отработает без ошибок:

```
char c = 'c';
double a = (double)c;
double b = c;
```

Comment: Ну вот, отличный полный ответ. Только к 'double' и подобным 'char' преобразуется только явно.

Comment: @VictorGorban, что значит _явно_? :-) обычно под _неявным_ преобразованием имеется ввиду возможность выполнения следующего кода: `double b = c;` где `c` переменная типа `char` просто присваивается, а не явно конвертируется в `double`.

Comment: Перепутал, извиняюсь. Еще раз спасибо за полный ответ.